# Apache Requested Operation Has Failed After IP Change

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I have setup a pretty basic Apache web server and it is only supposed to be serving my music directory upon requests.  Yesterday, I unplugged my modem (which gives me a new IP) to fix an internet connection issue. That is the only change I can think of that has happened, because today when I try to start Apache I receive "The requested operation has failed!"

There are no error logs being created in the /logs/error.log file.

I've tried adding Listen `newip:sameport` to the config file and that did not help.

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error message when trying to boot up my web server or if there are some error logs I can view for this?

Comment: When you tried to start Apache were you root ?  It sounds like you might not have had the privs required to start it ?

Comment: Yes, my account is an administrator and that has remained a constant factor. : /

Answer (score 0):

The external IP address change does not seem to be the cause of this error.

After looking at the Event Viewer in Windows 7 I was able to see an error:
`>>> (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80     .`

Then I ran `netstat -aon | findstr :80` and saw that a couple processes were listening on port 80 of my local machine, which may have been causing the issue.  After removing the few that I could like the antivirus and another vpn client I was still running into the issue due to ProcessID 4 (SYSTEM).

Finally, I just switched the internal port that Apache was listening on from 80 to something else so that there would be no conflict.